# Jupyterhub user home folder permissions mismatched on restarts

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have set up a single server with Google Auth Jupyterhub using Docker. You can find the setup scripts here - https://github.com/deepakputhraya/jupyterhub. The setup works well with multiple users able to login with separate home directories.

The problem arises when I update the Dockerfile or requirements.txt file and restart the server. Users whose accounts are created can log in but cannot access their home folders.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-196 ~]$ sudo docker exec -it jupyterhub /bin/sh
# ls -lah /home
total 64K
drwxr-xr-x 16 root      root      4.0K Oct 18 10:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root      root      4.0K Sep  4 15:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 15 abhilash  abhilash  4.0K Oct 31 10:51 abhilash
drwxr-xr-x  9 ajay      ajay      4.0K Oct 10 09:11 ajay
drwxr-xr-x  8 abhilash  abhilash  4.0K Sep  2 11:05 akshay
drwxr-xr-x  7 deepak    deepak    4.0K Oct  4 12:20 deepak
```

Logs:

```
[I 2019-10-31 14:57:14.985 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /hub/spawn-pending/deepak (deepak@127.0.0.1) 38.35ms
[I 2019-10-31 14:57:17.321 JupyterHub spawner:1387] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser --port=34405 --NotebookApp.default_url=/lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'runtime_dir'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 660, in main
    return SingleUserNotebookApp.launch_instance(argv)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 558, in initialize
    return super().initialize(argv)
  File "</opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1676, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1349, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 99, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 13, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/deepak'
[I 2019-10-31 14:57:18.274 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/spawn/deepak -> /hub/spawn-pending/deepak (deepak@127.0.0.1) 1014.98ms
[I 2019-10-31 14:57:18.332 JupyterHub pages:303] deepak is pending spawn
[I 2019-10-31 14:57:18.335 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /hub/spawn-pending/deepak (deepak@127.0.0.1) 17.16ms
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<BaseHandler.spawn_single_user() done, defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py:697> exception=HTTPError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 889, in spawn_single_user
    timedelta(seconds=self.slow_spawn_timeout), finish_spawn_future
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 922, in spawn_single_user
    % (status, spawner._log_name),
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Spawner failed to start [status=1]. The logs for deepak may contain details.)
[W 2019-10-31 14:57:44.492 JupyterHub user:678] deepak's server never showed up at http://127.0.0.1:34405/user/deepak/ after 30 seconds. Giving up
[E 2019-10-31 14:57:44.530 JupyterHub gen:593] Exception in Future <Task finished coro=<BaseHandler.spawn_single_user.<locals>.finish_user_spawn() done, defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py:800> exception=TimeoutError("Server at http://127.0.0.1:34405/user/deepak/ didn't respond in 30 seconds",)> after timeout
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 589, in error_callback
        future.result()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 807, in finish_user_spawn
        await spawn_future
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 654, in spawn
        await self._wait_up(spawner)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 701, in _wait_up
        raise e
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 669, in _wait_up
        http=True, timeout=spawner.http_timeout, ssl_context=ssl_context
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 234, in wait_for_http_server
        timeout=timeout,
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 177, in exponential_backoff
        raise TimeoutError(fail_message)
    TimeoutError: Server at http://127.0.0.1:34405/user/deepak/ didn't respond in 30 seconds
```

The folder permissions for user `akshay` is that of `abhilash`. New users who signup for the first time do not have this issue. Again this only happens when there is an update to Docker image. If I were to restart the server, it neither fixes the issue nor changes the user folder permissions map for other users.

Why are the permissions getting mismatched? How can this be fixed?